# Filtering Propel collection

Tags: php, combobox, propel

I'm trying do a linked combo between Country/State via Ajax.
The change combo events is ok. But i need help with the filtering via Propel.

```
// provincia == state ; pais == country :)
// $provincias contains only one "provincia". Because i have only one state in the       country.
$provincias = ProvinciasQuery::create()->filterByIdpais($_GET['pais']);

$data = array();

foreach($provincias as $provincia) {
$data[] = Array('id' => $provincia->getIdprovincia(), 'name' => $provincia->getProvincia())
}
```

This code fails with the next error:

> [20-Nov-2012 16:10:23 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Criterion::getIdprovincia()

Any idea ? Thanks !.

Comment: What is your model? What is inside `$_GET['pais']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use filter from query, you have to call `find()` at the end. Now in `$provincias` you have `Criteria` object, not the query result.

```
$provincias = ProvinciasQuery::create()->filterByIdpais($_GET['pais'])->find();
```

Comment: @ramiromd then do not forget to [check the doc](http://propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html) before asking a new question